# Pandas plotting routine fails with NoneType is not callable, but only when run inside pdb

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

The following code
If I run the following code in pdb (i.e. with `python -m pdb`)

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    import pandas as pd

    df=pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2],[63,146, 135]])
    df.plot.area()
```

it fails with a TypeError inside a numpy routine that's called by matplotlib:

```
> python -m pdb test_dtype.py 
> /home/jhaiduce/financial/forecasting/test_dtype.py(1)<module>()
-> if __name__=='__main__':
(Pdb) r
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
--Return--
> /home/jhaiduce/financial/forecasting/test_dtype.py(6)<module>()->None
-> df.plot.area()
(Pdb) c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 384, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/pdb.py", line 1726, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/pdb.py", line 1586, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/bdb.py", line 597, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jhaiduce/financial/forecasting/test_dtype.py", line 6, in <module>
    df.plot.area()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1496, in area
    return self(kind="area", x=x, y=y, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 972, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py", line 71, in plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 294, in generate
    self._post_plot_logic_common(ax, self.data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 473, in _post_plot_logic_common
    self._apply_axis_properties(ax.xaxis, rot=self.rot, fontsize=self.fontsize)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 561, in _apply_axis_properties
    labels = axis.get_majorticklabels() + axis.get_minorticklabels()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1201, in get_majorticklabels
    ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1371, in get_major_ticks
    numticks = len(self.get_majorticklocs())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1277, in get_majorticklocs
    return self.major.locator()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 2113, in __call__
    vmin, vmax = self.axis.get_view_interval()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1987, in getter
    return getattr(getattr(self.axes, lim_name), attr_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 781, in viewLim
    self._unstale_viewLim()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 776, in _unstale_viewLim
    self.autoscale_view(**{f"scale{name}": scale
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2932, in autoscale_view
    handle_single_axis(
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2895, in handle_single_axis
    x0, x1 = locator.nonsingular(x0, x1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 1654, in nonsingular
    return mtransforms.nonsingular(v0, v1, expander=.05)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2880, in nonsingular
    if maxabsvalue < (1e6 / tiny) * np.finfo(float).tiny:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 387, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py(387)__new__()
-> dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
(Pdb)
```

The error occurs only when run in the debugger; the program runs as normal when run outside the debugger.

Any idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: is the code you've show the entirety of the file?

Comment: Yes, this is the whole code.